# Is there a better way to set the odds to generating a random number and controling the limits?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do a game that has 20 rounds of play. I have assigned 0 thru 8 to represent the items in the game. I need the random number to be 90 percent of the time to be any number 0 thru 5. I need the numbers 6 and 7 to be 4 percent of the time. And, I need the 8 to be only 2 percent of the time. Below is the code I have and it works sometimes but often it generates way too many of the 6s, 7s, and 8's. The way I see the code is that it should be working most of the time correctly but does not. Is there a better way to control the random to get the percents I need to be more consistently?

```
' Get the random number position into array
Public Sub GetNumPositions(ByVal positions() As Integer)
    ' 20 rounds, each round 5 numbers
    ' we want 2 times (8), 4 times (6 and 7)
    ' 2% 8, 4% 6, 4% 7, and 90% times 0 thru 5
    For i As Integer = 0 To positions.Length - 1
        Dim p As Integer = rndNums.Next(100)

        If p < 90 Then
            positions(i) = p \ 15
        ElseIf p < 94 Then
            positions(i) = 6
        ElseIf p < 98 Then
            positions(i) = 7
        Else
            positions(i) = 8
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just fine. Here is a method to test it. It gathers some numbers and calculates their frequency:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim count = 100000000
    Dim positions(count) As Integer
    Dim frequencies(9) As Integer
    GetNumPositions(positions)
    For Each num In positions
        frequencies(num) += 1
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To 8
        Console.WriteLine(i & ": " & (100.0 * frequencies(i) / count) & " %")
    Next
End Sub
```

The result is:

```
0: 14.994567 %
1: 15.000016 %
2: 15.01366 %
3: 14.996542 %
4: 15.002074 %
5: 15.00325 %
6: 4.002246 %
7: 3.999337 %
8: 2.000603 %
```

As you can see, the frequencies match your input distribution very closely.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work just fine. That is a very nice test method. I must have something else wrong somewhere else in my program. The last few times I ran the game it gave the 6's about 7 or 8 percent and same for the 7's. Also, it gave about 4 percent on the 8's. I am not sure where the problem is to be giving that high of percent on those numbers. Thank you for your answer. I will keep looking in my code to see if I can narrow it down and may come back here to post it when I find the problem.

Comment: Nico, do you think somewhere else in my program it sees an Integer in a different way of calculations? Could I use Int32 or something else instead of Integer to help keep the percentages closer? I agree that I think this part of my code is fine but somewhere else is not keeping it consistent.

Comment: I don't think that this is a data type issue. The deviation from the target distribution may, of course, become larger if you generate fewer numbers. Maybe it is just that. But maybe it is a problem of how you use the numbers. I assume, you generate one `rndNums` at the beginning and not a new one each time you call this function.

Comment: Yes, I generate one rndNums at the beginning and not a new one each time the function is called. I will say this... it seems that the more players playing the game the more the percentages of the 6's, 7's, and 8's go higher. For example, when under 15 players it seems to work fine but when it goes 20 or more players it starts to increase. Not sure why that would make a difference. Everyone should be getting the same no matter how many players.

Comment: Have you actually measured the frequency or is this just a feeling?

Comment: I have not measured the frequency but have witnessed the results as they happen in the game and at end of game I get the totals for each item the numbers represent and can see the results are higher than the percentage that I have in the code.

Comment: only thing i can think of doing at this point is to write some if statements so that if the 6, 7, and 8 are higher than the percentage I need then pick another random again before sending to the players.